# Converting KMZ file with png images to shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convert, kmz

I have a KMZ file with data cell phone antenna coverage.

I try to convert with tool **kml to layer** but it converts only points. That information with coverage disappeared. I tried to use ET but it also returns only points.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the information of the coverage is in the png images then you can't convert those into shp.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to see the images inside your `*.kmz` by re-naming it to `*.zip` but images are raster data while shapefiles are a vector format.

You could investigate raster to vector conversion using ArcScan, if the images are two-coloured.